# How to tell who is the stronger chess player, for the purpose of fine tuning chess engines?

Tags: probability, statistics

This is a chess like question concerning how many games are required to tell who is the stronger player.

The application is in fine tuning chess engines. It is typical that during this process a chess engine will play some games with a modified version of itself. After the tests the most successful engine is used as a baseline and it again plays a series of games with a modified version of itself. This is perhaps best described as an incremental approach to fine tuning.

The problem is how many games do you have to play to have statistical valid data from the games when the engines may be very closely matched in ability?

I had a stab at this using the score (1 point for a win, 0.5 points for a draw and 0 for a loss) and a Chi squared table with 3 degrees of freedom and calculating what was required. I came up with this (small excerpt):

```
Games     95%*      97.5%*      99%*        99.5%*      99.9%*
5       4.5 / 0.5   - / -       - / -       - / -       - / -
6       5.0 / 1.0   5.5 / 0.5   - / -       - / -       - / -
8       6.5 / 1.5   7.0 / 1.0   7.5 / 0.5   - / -       - / -
9       7.0 / 2.0   7.5 / 1.5   8.0 / 1.0   8.5 / 0.5   - / -
12      9.0 / 3.0   9.5 / 2.5   10.0 / 2.0  10.5 / 1.5  11.5 / 0.5
* confidence level
```

Which I intend to use like this: if I played 5 games and the result is 4.5 to 0.5 or better then I have 95% confidence I found the stronger engine. If I played 6 games and the result is 4.5 to 1.5 or worse then I cannot tell which is the stronger engine with 95% confidence.

Have I done this the correct way? Should I have awarded 1 point for the draw also? Or used 2 degrees of freedom? Or a different approach altogether?

Comment: sorry it really mashed the 6 column table

Comment: Thanks for help - I'm not sure why this isn't a math question, but I found an answer. I am substantially correct - I just have to check what DOF I used. Others have done the same thing with binomial theorem.